# How to take input from template and store it in javascript variable in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I tried like this

app/template/print-dept.hbs

```
<form action="/print-dept-wise">
Department: <input type="text" id="dept"><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

app/template/print-dept-wise.hbs

```
{{#each model as |print|}}
Employee Id: {{print.empId}} <br/>
First Name: {{print.fname}} <br/>
Last Name: {{print.lname}} <br/>
Employee Dept: {{print.dept}} <br/>
<br/>
{{/each}}
```

app/route/print-dept-wise.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
model() {
var text = document.getParameterById("dept");
return Ember.$.getJSON('http://localhost/EmpDir/app/jsonRes/jsonR/'+text);
}
});
```

But it is not work as i expected

how can i change last part of my JSON url depending on user input?

Comment: To clarify: you want to make your AJAX request based on the input from the user? It's a little hard to tell what you're trying to do -- `getParameterById` isn't a method on `document`.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind properties in your templates to component / controller values and then send them to your route. Ember has some built in [Input helpers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/templates/input-helpers/) you can use.

So something like:

```
{{input value=department}}
```

Will bind what the user enters to a property called `value` you can then access in controller/ templates with `this.get('department')`